# How to get USB mouse support for guest host VM?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, mouse, linux-mint

I have a Logitech mouse connected to my computer, but I cannot use all of its capabilities in my virtual machine. In my virtual machine, the back button on my mouse does not work. In order for it to work, I have to manually go into the VM settings and disable the mouse on my host and enable it on my guest. I don't want to do this each time. Or is there a way to get it to automatically do this when I toggle between my guest and host (each time I press ctrl + alt)?

Comment: What VM software are you using? Did your Logitech mouse come with any software that had to be installed to enable extra functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated if you are using the VMWare Guest tools.  They should be giving you the extra sauce that you need to fully use your mouse.